# What are the hotkeys on a Belkin 2 port kvm switch?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

What are the hotkeys on a Belkin 2 port kvm switch?

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.belkin.com/support/download/downloaddetails.asp?download=1029&lang=1) :

> You can switch directly to any port by
>   entering the Switch port number you
>   wish to use. For example, if you press
>   “SCROLL LOCK”, “SCROLL LOCK”, “2”, the
>   computer on port 2 will be selected.
>
> AutoScan Mode In AutoScan mode, the
>   Switch remains on one port for eight
>   seconds before switching to the next.
>   This time interval cannot be changed.
>   To enable AutoScan mode, press “SCROLL
>   LOCK”, “SCROLL LOCK”, “S”.
>
> Note: There is no mouse or keyboard
>   control in this mode by design, in
>   order to prevent errors. If it were
>   enabled, the user could move the mouse
>   or use the keyboard while the KVM
>   Switch is switching to the next port.
>   This could interrupt communication
>   between the computer and Switch that
>   might cause erratic mouse movement, or
>   result in errant display of characters
>   when using the keyboard.
>
> To disable AutoScan mode, press the
>   space bar.

Answer (score 0):

scrollx2 arrow key up or down